# Request Missing an Accept Header in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the error below on production site while submitting :

```
Request Missing an Accept Header
```

this is my form :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Connect", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ConnectForm", @role = "form" }))
{
```

any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Is this for a single action or all of the actions inside your project? Also provide hosting details like web server and framework etc

Comment: it's for all of them

Comment: Can you put your hosting details in your question.

Comment: From where are you calling this from Postman or through web browser if web browser can you check the request and it's headers is it there or not.